# SQL INNER JOIN Unexpected Result

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have been trying to understand this for almost over 2hrs now and still I'm unable to understand the output of my `JOIN` query.

I have a table `gift` with the structure

```
+--------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------+
| giftid | giftname          | price | discount | availability |
+--------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------+
| G101   | Magic Mug         |   500 |        9 |           10 |
| G102   | Golf Set          |  3550 |        5 |           15 |
| G103   | Little Astronomer |  2000 |       20 |           18 |
| G104   | Renoir Paintings  |  1500 |       15 |           15 |
| G105   | French F          |  3000 |        7 |           10 |
| G106   | Magic Set         |  1300 |       30 |           30 |
+--------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------+
```

I am running `JOIN` on the same table and literally comparing the same column values. So, in theory result should be `12` rows. This is true for every column except `availability`.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT g1.giftid, g1.giftname, g1.discount, g1.availability FROM gift g1 JOIN gift g2 ON g1.availability=g2.availability;
```

If I change `g1.availability=g2.availability` to compare some other column, the output is `12 rows` which is expected.

Can anyone explain why this is not including the column values 18 and 30? Coz they're literally the same. It is selecting every other duplicate value but not these two.

Shouldn't a self join with comparison of the same column always return `all` of the values present in the table twice?

Regards

Comment: Please clearly & fully say what you expect & why you expect it with reference to authoritatitve documentation. Otherwise you are just asking us to rewrite it, which is too broad & a duplicate, & we can't address your misconceptions other than that you don't understand join, which you & we already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it gives back 10 rows as expected

only 10 and 15 are double, so you get 8 and as 18 and 30 are unique you get 2 more rows

> ```
> CREATE TABLE gift (
>   `giftid` VARCHAR(4),
>   `giftname` VARCHAR(17),
>   `price` INTEGER,
>   `discount` INTEGER,
>   `availability` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO gift
>   (`giftid`, `giftname`, `price`, `discount`, `availability`)
> VALUES
>   ('G101', 'Magic Mug', '500', '9', '10'),
>   ('G102', 'Golf Set', '3550', '5', '15'),
>   ('G103', 'Little Astronomer', '2000', '20', '18'),
>   ('G104', 'Renoir Paintings', '1500', '15', '15'),
>   ('G105', 'French F', '3000', '7', '10'),
>   ('G106', 'Magic Set', '1300', '30', '30');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT g1.giftid, g1.giftname, g1.discount, g1.availability 
> FROM gift g1 JOIN gift g2 
> ON g1.availability=g2.availability;
> ```

> ```
> giftid | giftname          | discount | availability
> :----- | :---------------- | -------: | -----------:
> G105   | French F          |        7 |           10
> G101   | Magic Mug         |        9 |           10
> G104   | Renoir Paintings  |       15 |           15
> G102   | Golf Set          |        5 |           15
> G103   | Little Astronomer |       20 |           18
> G104   | Renoir Paintings  |       15 |           15
> G102   | Golf Set          |        5 |           15
> G105   | French F          |        7 |           10
> G101   | Magic Mug         |        9 |           10
> G106   | Magic Set         |       30 |           30
> ```

> ```
> SELECT g1.giftid, g1.giftname, g1.discount, g1.availability , g2.*
> FROM gift g1 JOIN gift g2 
> ON g1.availability=g2.availability;
> ```

> ```
> giftid | giftname          | discount | availability | giftid | giftname          | price | discount | availability
> :----- | :---------------- | -------: | -----------: | :----- | :---------------- | ----: | -------: | -----------:
> G105   | French F          |        7 |           10 | G101   | Magic Mug         |   500 |        9 |           10
> G101   | Magic Mug         |        9 |           10 | G101   | Magic Mug         |   500 |        9 |           10
> G104   | Renoir Paintings  |       15 |           15 | G102   | Golf Set          |  3550 |        5 |           15
> G102   | Golf Set          |        5 |           15 | G102   | Golf Set          |  3550 |        5 |           15
> G103   | Little Astronomer |       20 |           18 | G103   | Little Astronomer |  2000 |       20 |           18
> G104   | Renoir Paintings  |       15 |           15 | G104   | Renoir Paintings  |  1500 |       15 |           15
> G102   | Golf Set          |        5 |           15 | G104   | Renoir Paintings  |  1500 |       15 |           15
> G105   | French F          |        7 |           10 | G105   | French F          |  3000 |        7 |           10
> G101   | Magic Mug         |        9 |           10 | G105   | French F          |  3000 |        7 |           10
> G106   | Magic Set         |       30 |           30 | G106   | Magic Set         |  1300 |       30 |           30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df7f0fefd25df752ec30cb493f4fcce1)*

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't a self join with comparison of the same column always return all of the values present in the table twice?

No, if the values in the join column are unique then the row will be joined to itself and one row returned. As per the previous answer you'll only get more rows when there are duplicate values in the joined column